# Forced Service Master Key on Secondary Replica

Tags: sql-server, encryption

As I was doing some testing with encryption on our test environment I used the FORCE command to have the SMK be the same on primary and secondary.

I've tried dropping the encrypted database on both primary and secondary and restore again a fresh copy and do the encryption again from start with new DMK. Then I tried to failover just to see if I can still decrypt and to my surprise I was still able to do so.

Question: Is there anyway to revoke/revert the "FORCE" command that I did?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to revoke/revert the "FORCE" command that i did?

If you have a previous copy of the SMK saved then you can restore it over the one you forced. However, you'll be in the same spot with some items encrypted with the old SMK and some with the forced. You'll need to add an encryptor by password to anything on the primary side [and then run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-control-dbmasterkey-password-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) `sp_control_db_master_key_password` on the secondary side to take care of this without the need of changing the SMK.